# 1D Tensor vs row/column matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray, tensor

Let two ndarrays in numpy be:

```py
>>> A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> B = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Now which can be called as a vector. B is a row matrix and a 2D Tensor as `B.ndim` is 2 and a row matrix is also called a vector in linear algebra. And A is a 1D tensor and so it is a vector by definition.

Comment: Not sure I follow -  what is the question?

Comment: Don't think so much in terms of vectors/matrix rows/columns. In numpy, everything is a ND-array. Then your operations can work on a common dimension, or broadcast, or aggregate. What exactly is the operation that you want to compute?

Comment: B has shape (1,3), and is more like a 'row vector'.  But by the `broadcasting` rules, A (3,) usually behaves the same.